# Shuffle keeping the similar elements in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a collection

```
$questions = ExaminationQuestion::where('question_set_id', $set->id)
                               ->where('marks', array_flip($marks)['2 Marks'])
                               ->inRandomOrder()
                               ->get();
```

It has subjects Aptitude, Chemistry, Math, English, Physics stored as 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

```
[
{
    id: 1,
    question_set_id: 1,
    subject: 0,
},
{
    id: 2,
    question_set_id: 1,
    subject: 0,
},
{
    id: 1,
    question_set_id: 1,
    subject: 1,
},
{
    id: 2,
    question_set_id: 1,
    subject: 1,
},
{
    id: 1,
    question_set_id: 1,
    subject: 2,
},
{
    id: 2,
    question_set_id: 1,
    subject: 2,
},
{
    id: 1,
    question_set_id: 1,
    subject: 3,
},
{
    id: 2,
    question_set_id: 1,
    subject: 3,
},
{
    id: 2,
    question_set_id: 1,
    subject: 4,
},
{
    id: 2,
    question_set_id: 1,
    subject: 4,
},
]
```

I want to display the $questions in random order by not shuffling each question but shuffling the subjects. Like Displaying all the questions of Math in random order then displaying all the questions of Physics in random order and so on. The subjects can shuffled in any order but questions should not shuffled like first displaying one question of Aptitude then another question of English then so on.
It should be display like this or in any order but according to the subject.

```
[
{
    id: 1,
    question_set_id: 1,
    subject: 3,
},
{
    id: 2,
    question_set_id: 1,
    subject: 3,
},
{
    id: 1,
    question_set_id: 1,
    subject: 2,
},
{
    id: 2,
    question_set_id: 1,
    subject: 2,
},
{
    id: 1,
    question_set_id: 1,
    subject: 0,
},
{
    id: 2,
    question_set_id: 1,
    subject: 0,
},
{
    id: 1,
    question_set_id: 1,
    subject: 4,
},
{
    id: 2,
    question_set_id: 1,
    subject: 4,
},
{
    id: 2,
    question_set_id: 1,
    subject: 1,
},
{
    id: 2,
    question_set_id: 1,
    subject: 1,
},
]
```

Comment: show your tables structure or data response how you store your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel's collections allow you to do this with a few helper methods:

```
$questions->groupBy('subject')->shuffle()->flatten(1);
```

`groupBy('subject')` will give you a 2d collection similar to the following:

```
[
  subject id => [question, question, ...],
  subject id => [question, question, ...],
  ..
]
```

`shuffle()` will shuffle the above collection.

`flatten(1)` will remove the grouping level, giving you a flat list of questions grouped by shuffled subject. the parameter `1` means "only flatten one level"; if you omit that you'll get wierd results.

Comment: Really a huge thanks for your answer. I have already tried groupBy but it was showing in a group. I did know aboutnthe flatten(1). So Big thanks

Comment: No problem. If it was helpful, could you mark my answer as correct by hitting the grey tick to the left of the answer?

Comment: Done. Can you upvote the question so that other will know.